# Left/right join to receive all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I join two tables together to get all rows from each, and enter NULL, where one is missing in the other one.

For example:

```
declare @t1 table (x int)
declare @t2 table (x int)

insert into @t1 select 2
insert into @t1 select 3
insert into @t1 select 4
insert into @t1 select 5

insert into @t2 select 1
insert into @t2 select 2
insert into @t2 select 5

select * 
from @t1 t1
left join @t2 t2 on t2.x = t1.x
```

The result should look like this:

```
t1.x    t2.x
NULL    1
2       2
3       NULL
4       NULL
5       5
```

Comment: [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719640/left-right-join-to-receive-all-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from @t1 t1
full outer join @t2 t2 on t2.x = t1.x
```

this is like left join, but will take all the records from both table even when there is no match, and will enter null when there is no match.

Comment: Thank you guys that was it!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from @t1 t1
FULL OUTER join @t2 t2 on t2.x = t1.x
```

Answer (score 2):

All rows from both tables are returned in a full outer join. SQL Server uses the following ISO keywords for outer joins specified in a FROM clause: LEFT OUTER JOIN or LEFT JOIN. RIGHT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT JOIN. FULL OUTER JOIN or FULL JOIN